# How to pass a ref to an server action?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using server actions to process data submitted with a form, and I want to clear the form into the action.

But the action does not receive the reference.

My action:

```
// actions/createVm.js
'use server'

export async function createVm(FormData) {
    const vm = await prisma.vm.create({
        data: {
            name: FormData.get("DisplayName"),
            ip: FormData.get("IpAddress"),
            group: {
                connect: { name: FormData.get("group") }
            }
        }
    })
    ref.current?.reset()
}
```

And the form :

```
// app/createVm/page.jsx
'use client'

import ButtonForm from "./button"
import { useRef } from "react"
import { createVm } from "@/actions/createVm"

export default function Form({ children }) {
  const ref = useRef(null)

    return(
        <div className="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
            <form className="space-y-6" action={createVm} ref={ref}>
                { children }
                <ButtonForm />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

How can I use the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useRef` is a client concept. It simply means "refrence to DOM element". You can't pass DOM element to the server (there is no DOM on the server).

### How to clear the data?

By using a client action:

```js
// app/createVm/page.jsx
"use client";

import ButtonForm from "./button";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { createVm } from "@/actions/createVm";

export default function Form({ children }) {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    async function handleSubmit(formData) {
        // there is no directive here

        // run the server action
        await createVm(formData);

        ref.current.reset();
    }

    return (
        <div className="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
            <form className="space-y-6" action={handleSubmit} ref={ref}>
                {children}
                <ButtonForm />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```js
// actions/createVm.js
"use server";

export async function createVm(FormData) {
    const vm = await prisma.vm.create({
        data: {
            name: FormData.get("DisplayName"),
            ip: FormData.get("IpAddress"),
            group: {
                connect: { name: FormData.get("group") },
            },
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly.
Thank you very much for the explanations and the code snippet.

Comment: Good to hear. Could you mark it as answered by clicking the check ✔️ icon next to the answe

Answer (score 0):

if you are using server action, you can access to form state with `useFormState`

```
// your action
import { createVm } from "@/actions/createVm"

const ref = useRef<HTMLFormElement | null>(null);

const [formState, action] = useFormState(
    createVm.bind(null, { arg1, arg2 }),
    { errors: {} }
  );

// if useFormState value changes, your component will rerendered
// inside here using ref you can have control on form
useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.success) {
      ref.current?.reset();      
    }
  }, [formState]);


 <form action={ createVm} ref={ref}>
 ....
 </form>
```